# Print word between two characters by going backward in the line

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I having problems in extracting the word from a line. What i want is that it picks the first word before the symbol # but after the /. Which is the only delimiter that stand out.

A line looks like this:

`,["https://picasaweb.google.com/111560558537332305125/Programming#5743548966953176786",1,["https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Is8rb8G1sb8/T7UvWtVOTtI/AAAAAAAAG68/Cht3FzfHXNc/s0-d/Geek.jpg",1920,1200]`

I want the word `Programming`.

To get that line i am using this which narrows it down.

```
sed -n '/.*picasa.*.jpg/p' 5743548866439293105
```

So i want it to pretty much find `#` and then go backward until it hit the first `/`. Then print it out. In this case the word should be `Programming` but could be anything.

I want it to be as short as possible and have experimented with

```
sed -n '/.*picasa.*.jpg/p' 5743548866439293105 | awk '$0=$2' FS="/" RS="[$#]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `sed` (slightly shortened for formatting but works on your original string as well):

```
pax> echo ',["https://p.g.com/111/Prog#574' | sed 's/^[^#]*\/\([^#]*\)#.*$/\1/'
Prog
pax>
```

Explaining in more detail:

```
    /---+------------------> greedy capture up to '/'.
   /    |
   |    | /------+---------> capture the stuff between '/' and '#'.
   |    |/       |
   |    ||       | /-+-----> everything from '#' to end of line.
   |    ||       |/  |
   |    ||       ||  |
's/^[^#]*\/\([^#]*\)#.*$/\1/'
                      ||
                      \+---> replace with captured group.
```

It basically searches for an entire line that has the pattern you want (first `#` following a `/`), whilst capturing (with the `\(` and `\)` brackets) just the stuff between `/` and `#`.

The substitution then replaces the entire line with just that captured text you're interested in (via `\1`).

Comment: How do i do if i just want one iteration of output? The file has many similar lines right now which means the word `programming` prints multiple times. If i want it to print just one.. is that possible? @paxdiablo

Comment: @AlMehdi: Yes, take the output of that and pipe it though `sort -u` (sort and uniquify).

Comment: @AlMehdi: Unless you want to actually stop on the first match, then you could do `sed -n 's/.../.../;T;p;q'` or `sed -n 's/.../.../;ta;b;:a;p;q'` depending on whether your `sed` has the capital `T` instruction (GNU `sed` does).

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` with some Perl regex extensions:

```
echo $string | grep -P -o "(?<=/)[^/]+(?=#)"
```

`-P` tells `grep` to use Perl extensions. `-o` tells `grep` to display only the matched text. To understand what gets matched, break the regex into three parts: `(?<=/)`, `[^/]+?`, and `(?=#)`. The first part says that the matched text must follow a '/', without including the '/' in the match. The second parts matches a string of non-'/' characters. The last part says that the matched text must be immediately followed by a '#', without including the '#' in the match.

Another grep, using the "\K" feature to "throw away" the match up to the last '/' before the '#':

```
# Match as much as possible up to a '/', but throw it away, then match as much as you can
# up to the first #
echo $string | grep -oP ".*/\K.+(?=#)"
```

Using `cut` and `awk` to get the first field (splitting on #) followed by the last field (splitting on /):

```
echo $string | cut -d# -f1 | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

Using some temporary variables and bash's parameter expansion facilities:

```
$ FOO=["https://picasaweb.google.com/111560558537332305125/Programming#5743548966953176786",1,["https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Is8rb8G1sb8/T7UvWtVOTtI/AAAAAAAAG68/Cht3FzfHXNc/s0-d/Geek.jpg",1920,1200]
$ BAR=${FOO%#*}      # Strip the last # and everything after
$ echo $BAR
[https://picasaweb.google.com/111560558537332305125/Programming
$ BAZ=${BAR##*/}     # Strip everything up to and including the last /
$ echo $BAZ
Programming
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/.*\/\([^#]*\)#.*/{s//\1/;q};d' file
```